# Zoom in jumps to another part on the screen illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, zoom

I recently installed CC and am using the zoom command + and I expect it usually to zoom in closer to where I am but it keeps jumping to another place on the screen. Assuming this can be fixed in preferences?

Comment: Spacebar+Command (Mac) or Spacebar+Ctrl (Win) and drag the mouse to zoom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no selections made, using <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> zooms in to the centre of the current view. If you want it to zoom in on something specific, select an object first.  If you don't want it to do this, deselect everything first using <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

If you want to disable zooming on selected objects, in *Edit > Preferences > Selection & Anchor display >* uncheck *Zoom to Selection*.

Alternatively use a mouse with a centre scroll wheel, and mouse over where you want to zoom, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> as you rotate the scroll wheel.

Alternatively use the Zoom Tool <kbd>Z</kbd> to click and drag where you want to zoom. Dragging to the right zooms in, dragging to the left zooms out.